# Count Parse installation records

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is there a way to count the number of Parse installations records?
I could not query in my App so I did it using cloud code. But still I can't query.

I'd like to count the number of installations per versionNumber and show this in my Admin Activity in the App.

Any Suggestions?

Error when trying to do a count via cloudecode:
- Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.
- Error generating response. ParseError {
  code: 141,
  message: 'Clients aren\'t allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.' }

Answer (score 0):

Key to the solutions was adding: **useMasterKey: true**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("countInstallations", function(request, response) {
    var qInstallation = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var sVersion = request.params.version;
    var sResult = "";

    qInstallation.equalTo("versionNumber",parseInt(sVersion));
    qInstallation.count({
        useMasterKey: true, 
        success: function(number) {
            sResult = number;
            response.success(sResult);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(0);
        }
    });
});
```

From my App I call this cloud function like this which will return the count for version 39.

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("version","39");
try {
    Log.d("MyApp","result:" +ParseCloud.callFunction("countInstallations",parameters));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```